# Python3 scraper. Doesn't parse the xpath till the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm using **lxml.html** module

```
from lxml import html   

page = html.parse('http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution')

# print(page.content)

unis = page.xpath('//tr/td[@valign="top" and @style="width: 50%;padding-right:15px"]/h3/text()')

print(unis.__len__())

with open('workfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for uni in unis:
        f.write(uni + '\n')
```

The website right here (http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution#Z) is full of universities.

The problem is that it parses till the letter 'H' (244 unis).
I can't understand why, as I see it parses all the HTML till the end.

I also documented my self that 244 is not a limit of a list or anything in python3.

Comment: Consider using `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` ?

Comment: the same, as I said, it parses the HTML till the end.
So the problem is not in the request function I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That HTML page simply isn't HTML, it's totally broken. But the following will do what you want. It uses the [BeautifulSoup](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) parser.

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import parse
import urllib

url = 'http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution'
page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
unis = page.xpath('//tr/td[@valign="top" and @style="width: 50%;padding-right:15px"]/h3/text()')
```

See http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#really-broken-pages for more info.

Comment: is it for python3? Cause It doesn't identify the urlopen function.

Comment: Sorry, tested it with Python 2. For Python 3 you need to add `request`. Answer updated. But note that you might run into another problem with lxml: `NameError: name 'unichr' is not defined` This is fixed in later lxml versions (see http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.soupparser-pysrc.html for reference).

Comment: BTW, to make you XPath expression less dependent on the formatting, maybe you should use `//tr/td/h3[following-sibling::br]/text()` instead.

Comment: Or to mimic Mad Matts solution, use `//tr/td/h3/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.))>0]`

Answer (score 1):

For web-scraping i recommend you to use [BeautifulSoup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) 
With bs4 this is easily done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

universities = []
result = urllib.request.urlopen('http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution#Z')

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.read(),'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='table')
for t in table:
    rows = t.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')
    for r in rows:
        # there are also the A-Z headers -> check length
        # there are also empty headers -> check isspace()
        headers = r.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='h3' and tag.text.isspace()==False and len(tag.text.strip()) > 2)
        for h in headers:
            universities.append(h.text)
```